# Highcharts: Change hover style in line chart when hovering over legend

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The default behavior of the line chart is to provide a hover state when hovering over the legend. The hover action also affects the style of the series pertaining to the current legend item. Is there a way to control the styles applied to the series when hovering over the legend?
I would like to control the width of the series in the chart when the legend is being hovered over.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this API might help you.

API: `plotOptions.line.states.hover.lineWidth` Link: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.states.hover.lineWidth

Jsfiddle link: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-states-hover-linewidth/)

Comment: is there a way where we can programmatically change it at anytime?